# How do I show that two vector lines are parallel?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let L$_{1}$ and L$_{2}$ be lines defined by

$$\vec{x} = \vec{w_{0}} + s\vec{u}, s \in \mathbb{R}\\and\\\vec{y} = \vec{w_{1}} + t\vec{v}, t \in \mathbb{R}, respectively\\$$
Show that L$_{1}$ and L$_{2}$ are parallel if and only if $\vec{u}$ = k$\vec{v}$ for some k $\in\mathbb{R}$

Now, I don't know how to answer this question. I did watch the following tutorials: [Parallel lines from equation](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/geometry/hs-geo-analytic-geometry/hs-geo-parallel-perpendicular-eq/v/parallel-lines-3) and [Parallel, intersecting, skew and perpendicular lines](https://youtu.be/r5DwyBFxD7Q) 
It doesn't really correspond to my question though. I also read through my textbook about lines and planes in 3-space and I also didn't get what I'm looking for. If you can show me or guide me to the correct answer I would much appreciate it.

Comment: Before you can do anything to solve this problem, you have to have a definition of parallel lines. What’s yours?

Comment: I think you mean $\vec{u}$ = k$\vec{\color{red}v}$ for some k $\in\mathbb{R}$

Comment: Two lines in two-dimensional Euclidean space are said to be parallel if they do not intersect. ... Therefore, parallel lines in three-space lie in a single plane. Sounds good?

Comment: Just to have an idea, take the first equation and note that $\vec{w_0}$ (let's call it P) lies on the line (why? Put s=0). Now, let the origin be $O$. Hence $\vec{x}=\vec{OX}, \vec{w_0}=\vec{OP}$. The segment $\vec{PX} (=x-w_0)$ lies on the line. Hence the line is parallel to $\vec{u}$. Likewise, line 2 is parallel to $\vec{v}$. Hence if the two lines are parallel, $\vec{u}$ and $\vec{v}$ should be scaler multiple of each other.

Comment: Could you draw an example of your explanation? It would really help me visualize what you mean. I want to remember this, not just copy and paste.

Comment: @Clint The point here is that in whatever textbook or set of notes you got this question from, there probably is an established definition of "parallel" that you're supposed to start from for this proof.

Comment: @Clint Note that "parallel lines in $3$-space lie in a single plane" is not a definition.  That said, we could potentially work with the definition that **two lines are parallel if they are co-planar and have no intersection**, which seems to be what you've been getting at.

Comment: I think @Koro's comment is the correct answer but I need to first understand it though.

Comment: @amd my definition is as follow: One way to check two given parametric lines if they are parallel or not is to use their direction vectors to compare if the ratios of the coordinates of the direction vectors give you the same answer then the lines are parallel. This is only applicable if both lines are given to you and all the values are known.  Another way is to check the norm or magnitude of both direction vectors. The norms of the direction vectors will be multiple of each other if the lines are parallel and the initial points will either be the same or also multiple of each other.

Comment: If that’s your definition of parallel lines, then there’s nothing to prove as it is a restatement of the proposition in your question.

Comment: @amd are you talking about the ratios of the slopes of $\vec{w_0} and \vec{w_1}$ or sentence reading show that the lines are parallel...?